# Tell Glide not to load images if set in preferences

Tags: android, android-glide

I have several `RecyclerView`'s inside my app, and all of them have items which have an `ImageView`, which are further populated with `Glide`, like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load(imageUrl)
 .asBitmap()
 .error(R.drawable.placeholder_avatar)
 .centerCrop()
 .into(mAvatarImageView);
```

In my Preference screen, users can disable loading of all remote images to save bandwidth.
What's the best way to tell `Glide` not to load images, without using a classic if-else conditions inside all `RecyclerView` adapters, which violates the DRY principle?

I'm looking for a method like this:

```
.shouldLoad(UserSettings.getInstance().isImageLoadingEnabled());
```

Comment: From what I've experienced on Glide, they have no options on NOT TO LOAD, because it doesn't make sense. you can make classic if else statement using the preference you want using: if (UserSettings.getInstance().isImageLoadingEnabled()) {}

Comment: Only reliable source is https://bumptech.github.io/glide/ for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will decide to use `Kotlin` you can create needed extension function:

```
fun <T> RequestBuilder<T>.shouldLoad(neededToLoad : Boolean) : RequestBuilder<T> {
    if(!neededToLoad) {
        return this.load("") // If not needed to load - remove image source
    }
    return this // Continue without changes
}
```

Then you can use it, as you describe in question:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .shouldLoad(false)
        .into(imageView)
```

It's fair to say, that you can create only one `Kotlin` file with `shouldLoad()` function and use it in `Java`, but code becomes ugly:

```
shouldLoad(Glide.with(this)
                .load(imageUrl), false)
            .into(imageView);
```

OR

```
RequestBuilder<Drawable> requestBuilder = Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageUrl);
requestBuilder = shouldLoad(requestBuilder, true);
requestBuilder.into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Glide v4, there is a request option specifically designed for this purpose: `RequestOptions.onlyRetrieveFromCache(boolean flag)`. When enabled, only resources already present in memory or disk cache are loaded, effectively preventing loads from the network and saving bandwidth.

If you use Glide v4 Generated API, this option is directly available on the `GlideRequest` returned by `GlideApp.with(context).asBitmap()`.
Otherwise, you have to create a `RequestOptions` with this flag enabled and `apply` it :

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().onlyRetrieveFromCache(true);
Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
    .apply(options)
    .error(R.drawable.placeholder_avatar)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(mAvatarImageView);
```

Comment: what if the user wants to enable fetching remote images? he will still have to make an if condition

Comment: You can pass `!UserSettings.getInstance().isImageLoadingEnabled()` to `onlyRetrieveFromCache` instead of `true` in my example. This way, users can enable/disable fetching of remote images from the Preference Screen.

Comment: I stumbled across this but the UI wouldn't be great with it. Imagine a `RecyclerView` which has items with randomly loaded images. Besides that, the users would complain that the images are still loading, although there are loaded from the cache.